# how to display a button only for 5 seconds

Tags: android, timer

I would like to know how to display a button only for five seconds and if clicked then timer should increase for another five seconds with button in different position. I used scheduleatfixedrate method but it stops my application once i click it. My platform is android. Please help me someone!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, positioning did't cover here, because I don't know what you want, but visibility change is done

```
private long lastClicked;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lastClicked = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    });
    lastClicked = System.currentTimeMillis();
    button.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastClicked > 5000) {
                button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                button.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
```

}